# Magento with RedisLab Redis Cluster Backend

Tags: magento, redis, redislabs

Magento RedisLab cluster Integration Problem

After we deploy cluster redis database , FPC and Session working perfectly but when we add cluster redis ( RedisLab ) instance with Magento Cache section we are facing one problem.

When click ADD TO CART >> show cannot add product

Backend Error

```
  Next exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'Error cleaning cache by mode matchingAnyTag: ERR CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot (command='SUNION', key='zc:ti:da3_QUOTE_2156255')' in /var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Cache.php:209
    Stack trace:
    3
    #6 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(464): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->cleanModelCache()
    #7 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(333): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
    #8 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->_afterSave()
    #9 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1966): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
    #10 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(459): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->save()
    #11 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(223): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save()
    #12 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
    #13 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
    #14 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #15 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #16 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #17 /var/www/magento/index.php(85): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #18 {main}
```

If i disable the exception then its working file

/var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Cache.php:209

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

- Just got the same exception like you , I believe that case belong to your custom work try to make magento working with redis-cluster
- My solution :

  - just remove exception in redis-client.php library first and return IP:PORT
  - find the correct client by byHash function in redis-cluster.php
  - execute the command with correct client
- Need to overwrite load , remove , _removeByMatchingTags...